# Any possible cause for stutter issue on new PC build?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, performance, nvidia-graphics-card, amd-ryzen

I have built a new PC with the following specs:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER
- RAM: Corsair Vengeance LPX 16GB (2x8GB)
- Motherboard: MSI MPG X570 Gaming Edge WiFi

Ever since I started using the PC I have been experiencing a stuttering issue where things would slow down or freeze for between half a second up to 3 seconds or so. The stutters seem to happen randomly as they happen no matter what I am doing on the system. I have had stutters happen just minutes between the previous one, but they sometimes do not happen for many hours at a time.

I have been trying to figure out what could be the cause of this issue and I  keep coming up dry. As of me posting this, I have tried the following solutions:

- Ran a RAM tester; ran for a few hours and everything came up with 0 errors.
- Reseated my RAM.
- Swapped the RAM sticks between slots.
- Monitored task manager for spikes in CPU usage and/or GPU usage during stutters/freezes. (No correlation between spikes and stutters.)
- Monitored temperatures of CPU and GPU during stutters/freezes. (Temperatures generally seemed fine; average about 50-60C most of the time.)
- Reseated my GPU.
- Uninstalled all traces of display drivers using DDU in safe mode and reinstalled the latest drivers for my GPU.
- Updated all drivers in general using Driver Booster 7.
- Installed the chipset drivers provided on the [AMD website](https://www.amd.com/en/support/chipsets/amd-socket-am4/x570).

Quick side note regarding the chipset driver installation: Attempting to install the chipset drivers from the [MSI website](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/support/MPG-X570-GAMING-EDGE-WIFI.html#down-driver&Win10%2064) causes my system to lag beyond belief during the installation and post-closing of the installer. The first time I tried installing the chipset drivers from the MSI website resulted in a failed install. However, running it again after restarting my system due to the lag resulted in a "successful" install. I am unsure if the install truly was successful as the process seemed to happen much faster than before.

- Ran CrystalDiskInfo to see if my SSD health was degraded. (Everything came up fine.)

I am lost as to what to do next. If anyone has had this issue before and found a solution, please let me know. If you have any more questions regarding my build, I will try to answer them the best I can. I hope the solution to this issue is relatively simple and I am just stupid for not noticing it sooner.

Thanks again!

Comment: I'd say the chipset driver sounds a bit shady to me - perhaps uninstall it in Device Manager and do a clean install of the drivers again?

Comment: @QuickishFM I ran the chipset driver installer from AMD again and everything went through fine. The ones provided by MSI though still cause the unbearable lag as soon as I start running the installer. Another note for the MSI provided drivers, I am unable to shutdown the PC through Windows after running the installer. The shutdown loading screen just spins indefinitely.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? If not, have you tried updating your bios?